# Время работы скрипта

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Скриптом AJAX отправляется запрос. Если обработка занимает более 2 минут, то происходит ошибка.
Помогите, пожалуйста, что делать в таком случае, чтобы браузер ждал ответ от скрипта более 2 минут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Браузер ждет ответа неограниченно долго - пока открыто tcp-соединение. Я регулярно захожу на страницы которые открываются по 5-10-15 минут.

Скорее всего соединение рвётся на стороне сервера по таймауту скрипта или промежуточным прокси или реверс-прокси сервером по таймауту отсутствия данных в соединении.

Для решения таймаута со скриптом - нужно смотреть настройки сервера и выставлять большие значения.

Для решение проблем с прокси - время от времени отправлять в соединение или очередную порцию данных или что-то левое, вроде пары тысяч пробелов чтобы соединение оставалось активным.

Comment: Проверил время выполнение скрпита = 1,4339088527953 сек , команда set_time_limit(2); выполняется.

Comment: у меня сайт на хостинге, видимо проблема в таймауте со скриптом

Comment: не совсем понимаю почему время выполнения скрипта меньше 2 секунд, а ждать приходится минутами.

Comment: т.е. не понятно тогда к какому параметру можно привязаться, если к примеру, задать функцию отслеживания, прошло 1 минута 50 секунд и она отдает все что готово, плюс какой-нибудь индикатор, который сообщает на каком месте была остановка.

Comment: Попробуйте: set_time_limit(200) + попробуйте скрипт вроде sleep(100); print 'OK' чтобы проверить прерывается ли скрипт из-за таймаута или по другим причинам. Если из-за таймаута - проконсультируйтесь с хостером на тему какой он и можно ли его увеличить. Если по-другой причине - отладка и выяснение.

Comment: Да, все именно так. Но установка set_time_limit() ничего не меняет. Видимо дело в установках хостинга. Возможно что-то с этим сделать или обойти проблему?

Comment: Тут нужно обратиться в поддержку хостинга, описать свою задачу, описать проблему. Поддержка подскажет как это делается в их системе и можно ли такое делать - на разных хостингах могут быть разные ограничения, так что универсального ответат тут нут.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на вывод `phpinfo()` на предмет значения `max_execution_time`. Если оно близко к 120 (секундам) - проблема в нём.

В таком случае Вам поможет увеличение (или выставление в 0, то есть "без ограничений") этого лимита с помощью [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-time-limit.php).

Comment: Да, все именно так. Но установка set_time_limit() ничего не меняет. Видимо дело в установках хостинга. Возможно что-то с этим сделать или обойти проблему?

Comment: что значит "установка set_time_limit() ничего не меняет"? каково значение `max_execution_time` в `phpinfo()` до установки `set_time_limit()` руками, каково после?